# How do I add hair to these eyebrows?

Tags: modeling, particles, hair

I've been struggling with this for hours. At first I tried just adding hair particles where the eyebrows should go on my character but that wasn't working so I made these eyebrow meshes. I don't want them to look like this (flat and thick) in the final render though. I want them to look like hair strands. I tried adding hair particles to the eyebrows but they ended up shooting out the back side for some reason. How do I properly add hair to these eyebrows? If this helps, the eyebrows are just mirrored planes with a solidify modifier.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you can do:

1. Here's your eyebrow's replica:

   [image]
   I added a *Subdivision Subsurface* modifier too (This doesn't work as desired unless you have quite a good amount of vertices. More vertices equals more control).
2. Added the Hair particles and kept the *length* long to make the change more apparent.

   [image]
3. Disable the particle system, go into *Weight Paint* mode (you'll find it along with the *Object mode*, *Edit mode* and others. Set the *strength* to 1, *weight* to 1 and *radius* as you desire (but not too big). Paint the areas red wherever you want the hair to grow. If you want to remove red from anywhere, simply set weight to 0.

   [image]
4. Go back to *Object Mode* and go to the *Vertex Group* properties. Rename the vertex group as you'd like (I renamed it as hair).

   [image]
5. Go to your particle system, open the *vertex groups* tab, and set *Density* to the vertex group you just renamed.

   [image]
6. Mine was still looking a little crooked, so I adjusted the Weight Paint colouring a bit more, increased the number of hairs, and reduced the length of the hair. Here's what mine looks like.

   [image]

Note: If the hair looks like it's crowded at one spot, like mine, go into *edit mode* and distribute the vertices as evenly as possible. However, this is apparent because my object still has a low vertex count. It won't look too bad if you have a really high vertex count.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the tip

Comment: Not a problem. fellow... blenderer??? ahaha :)